# Measuring Torque in a bicycle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, applied-mechanics, torque, bicycles

1. How to measure torque in a bicycle?
2. how much newtons will produce by the pedal of the cycle ?

Comment: Are you wanting the torque in some part of the frame? The main upright?

Comment: Do you know the newtons provided by the cyclist? A "normal" rider or Chris Boardman?

Comment: How to measure experimentally? Or how to calculate? Peak torque or average? You need to give *much* more information. You might start with why you are looking for this information?

Comment: A starting guess might be the weight of the rider times the crank length.

Answer (score 2):

Most bicycle cranks are 170mm and they vary from 165mm to 180mm.

Skilled bicyclist can apply up to 1.5 to 2 times their weight on the pedals in burst of power to pass a race competitor by leveraging the handles and using the entire frame of the bike as a lever.

Say a rider weighs 160lbs.

$$T = 160*1.5*0.56=136lbs.ft$$

As an aside, a fit bicyclist can produce continuous 160-180 watts energy.